# ECL Connector Proxy Settings

Tags: web8.5, ecl

How can I configure proxy settings in ExternalContentLibrary.xml
which would be applied to all the calls made from ECL connector?

Comment: Can you please provide more information on why you need to set proxy.Do you have issue configuring the ECL and not able to get the ECLitems. are you asking is there any property for proxy to add it to the ECL mountPoint.

Comment: API calls (with which external library is exposed) need Internet connection. Of course I can add Proxy settings under the mountpoint, read those within the connector code and attach the proxy to HttpWebRequest calls that are made from the connector. But I am wondering if the connector framework itself makes it easy to attach the proxy without any coding by adding it to the configuration ?

Comment: Did you ever implement this? Would be nice to see something proposed in IDEAS to improve the connection framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for Proxy Settings in ECL. You need to implement it at the connector.